# Make PHP variable have html link as its value

Tags: php, html, email, hyperlink

I am trying to assign an html link as the value of a php variable.  Like so, (which I know doesn't work):

```
$mlink = <a href = "download.php">Download Link</a>;
```

I am trying to send an email with a link as the message of the email.  I am using mail() to do so. Here is my code for the script which sends the mail.  This is where I want to use the $mlink variable that has the html link as its value.

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['email1'];
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = $mlink;
$from = "somewhere@somewhere.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) )
{
    echo ("<p>Mail Sent!</p>");
}
else
{
    echo ("<p>Mail could not be sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

I am assigning the value of $mlink within another script that calls on this one.  I can post that script as well. I just wasn't sure if that was necessary.

I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.  I've tried to use echo but it gives me an error when I do so in a variable assignment statement. I've tried a few other things but they all either give me an error or unwanted output.  I am at a loss as to how to make this work :(

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!

Comment: Try `$mlink = "<a href = 'download.php'>Download Link</a>";`

Comment: Or $mlink = "<a href = \"download.php\">Download Link</a>";

Comment: Instead of giving a man one fish to eat, teach him how to catch fish. You're looking for "strings", and you can learn about them here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thank you all for the great responses! I just got out of a work meeting.  I will soon test my project and see if I have implemented the solutions correctly. I still have a lot to learn. I am very grateful for the assistance. I will post back as soon as I have tested this on our server. I will definitely study up on all the links posted because I would love to be able to catch my own fish! :)

Comment: I was using xampp and testing this on localhost without a mail server. It was sending the "email" to mailoutput folder within the xampp directory as a text file, so it was interpreting everything as strictly text. I think that had a hand in why I was confusing myself, along with my noobness, of course!

Answer (score 1):

To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set **Content-type:text/html** .
this way , your code will be interpreted as html code not as plain text:

```
 <?php

 $mlink = "download.php";

 $to = $_POST['email1'];
 $subject = "Test mail";
 $message = "<a href=" . $mlink . ">Download Link</a>";
 $from = "somewhere@somewhere.com";

 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From:" . $from;

 if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) )
 {
     echo ("<p>Mail Sent!</p>");
 }
 else 
 {
     echo ("<p>Mail could not be sent!</p>");
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: He should use a MIME email class and send one that contains both HTML *and* text. Nothing worse than HTML-only emails...

Comment: His lack of understanding of the concept of strings was the biggest issue, but this IS a valid point.

Comment: He said he tried lot of solutions,may be this is the cause,any way this answer covers two problems,link and content-type

Comment: @FaceOfJock There needs to be an `http` included in Email whether it be HTML or plain text format. "Email" doesn't know where the file is coming from or resides, therefore a server i.e.: `http://www.example.com` needs to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**:

As noted from comments in another answer, am providing some added information that the OP can look into doing and to [search the Internet (Google link example)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=how%20to%20send%20html%20and%20plain%20text%20email%20at%20the%20same%20time%20in%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr) on achieving this.

**How to send a multipart email using HTML and plain text:**

- The trick is in the header information. You will need to create two copies of the email, one plain text and another in HTML format.

### EDIT (working example in HTML format only)

In order for a link to be downloadable from a Website (`WWW`), this is an `http` call, thefore a server variable needs to first be assigned.

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['email1'];
$subject = "Test mail";
$server = "http://www.example.com";
$mlink = "download.php";

$message = "

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<a href=\"$server/$mlink\">Download Link</a>

</body>
</html>

";

$from = "somewhere@somewhere.com";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:" . $from;

if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) )
{
    echo ("<p>Mail Sent!</p>");
}
else
{
    echo ("<p>Mail could not be sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

---

#### Original answer

Here is an example (not for Emailing purposes, but on Website only):

```
<?php

$mlink = "download.php";

echo "<a href='$mlink'>Download Link</a>";

echo "<br>";

echo "<a href='$mlink'>$mlink</a>"; // displays file name

?>
```